# User inputs stringstream, then need convert to string to pass in function parameters

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I am trying to ask the user for a stringstream, then convert it to a string so I can pass it in a functions parameters. How can I do this ? :

```
string Nm;
stringstream ss;
cout << " Please enter where the charge was made " << endl;
                 cin >> Nm;
                 ss.str();
                 cca.doCharge(Nm);
```

Comment: You can't really ask the user for a stringstream.

Comment: Then how would I ask the user for a string, and if they input lets say GREEN GRASS, would that be acceptable? Because right now if the user is inputting a string it only allows one word.

Comment: [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) would likely be a better fit.

Comment: Thank you. So when I get rid of cin >> Nm and add getline(cin,Nm) my code will run but it will skip the part were the user will input Nm. Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20getline%20skipping

Comment: Mixing `operator>>` (field oriented) with `std::getline` (line oriented) input is problematic. `operator>>` tends to leave new-lines sitting in the input buffer, where unwary use of `std::getline` will read them as an empty line without waiting for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to pass the actual stream to the function, or the string? The following passes the stream:

```
std::string str;
std::stringstream ss;

std::getline(std::cin, str);
ss.str( str );

cca.doCharge(ss);
```

This passes the string:

```
cca.doCharge(str);
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to pass the string (str) of the stream. When in doubt better put solutions to both problems in the answer than asking a question in it.